# LINQ query returning duplicates even though grouped

Tags: linq

I have the following query and I am trying to get the average ItemCost for each Location. The `Shop.cs` objects and the `Item.cs` objects are linked by ShopId. Each shop has a location and I want to get the average item cost for the items for each location.

```
        var query = from s in shops
                    join e in items
                        on s.shopId equals e.shopId into se
                    group se by new
                    {
                        Location= s.location,
                        Average= se.Average(x => x.ItemCost)
                    } into g
                    orderby g.Key.Average descending
                    select new
                    {
                        Location = g.Key.location,
                        AverageCost = g.Key.average,
                    };
```

The output of the above is:

```
London   4.65
Scotland  3.44
London   9.28
London 3.25
```

I can't figure out why London is being returned as duplicates in the output and also has different Item values because I am grouping the data in the query. **What LINQ do I need to get the following output?:**

```
London  5.64 (with all London records grouped)
Scotland 3.44
```

Comment: I would verify the two _London_ entries are the same, that is check your whitespace in your data source

Comment: @nina coder thank you for your suggestion. I have added methods to clean the data before it is queried using LINQ eg remove the whitespace with location.Trim(); but it still returns duplicate London records.

Comment: Have you verified that there are not multiple London entries in your source? In other words, are there multiple Shops with the same Location?

Comment: yes, there are multiple shops with the same location. But I need the query to group by location in this situation.

Comment: I understand the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is that you are grouping on a key of Location and Average Cost which is not the same as just grouping by location. You will need to group by just location then determine your average cost.

Here is what I came up with:

```
var newQuery =
    from s in shops
    join e in items on s.ShopId equals e.ShopId into se
    group se by s.Location into g
    select new { Location = g.Key, AverageCost = g.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Cost)).Average() } into t
    orderby t.AverageCost
    select new { t.Location, t.AverageCost}
```

**Input:**

```
var shops = new List<Shop>()
    {
        new Shop() {ShopId = 1, Location = "London"},
        new Shop() {ShopId = 2, Location = "Scotland"},
        new Shop() {ShopId = 3, Location = "London"},
        new Shop() {ShopId = 4, Location = "London"},
    };

var items = new List<Item>()
   {
        new Item{Cost = 1, ShopId = 1},
        new Item{Cost = 5, ShopId = 1},
        new Item{Cost = 2, ShopId = 2},
        new Item{Cost = 2, ShopId = 3},
        new Item{Cost = 3, ShopId = 4},
   };
```

**Output:**

```
Location AverageCost
London   2.75
Scotland 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from s in shops join e
     in items 
    on s.shopId equals 
    e.shopId into se 
    group se by new { Location= s.location} into 
    g orderby g.Average(x=>x.e.ItemCost)
     descending 
    select new
     { Location = g.Key.Location, AverageCost = g.Average(x=>x.e.ItemCost)};
```

Try the above code. I have removed average column from group by clause since you need to group by location only.

Comment: Thank you for your code snippet but the following two lines where it should be possible to select ItemCost do not have it in the intellisense: g orderby g.Average(x=>x.ItemCost) and     AverageCost = g.Average(x=>x.ItemCost)}; don't allow for x.ItemCost to be selected.